# Automating Azure deploy

Tags: powershell, azure, asp.net-mvc-5, azure-web-app-service, azure-blob-storage

I have created a configurable mvc5 application, lets say a kind of template (web UI with sql server and entity framework) with configuration values in a database table

Our Customers will fill in a form that includes configuration parameters like Application Name, Logo file, Footer statement (the same parameters as the template mvc5)

upon completion of the form, I want to automate the following

1. create new database for this customer
2. Create new blob service (there is an element of file storage in the app)
3. Deploy an instance of the template MVC
4. Update database with configuration parameters
5. provide the link of working Azure app to the customer

Is this possible? Most of SO and google results seem to be pointing towards to automating build and deploy to an existing Azure instance, which is not what I am after

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that we can do that via  Azure Resource Template. We could link WebApp source code to GitHub repository, more info please refer to [document](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/app-service-web/app-service-web-arm-from-github-provision.md).
We also could create our arm template easily with VS tools. We could add/remove resources as we need. More detail steps please refer to [Creating and deploying Azure resource groups through Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/vs-azure-tools-resource-groups-deployment-projects-create-deploy). About how to set template parameters, we could edit the parameter value in the xxx.parameters.json.

Comment: thanks for the pointers +1 for that. I will try and Keep this updated. Thanks Tom

Comment: Do you have any update about this thread? if any concern please let me know.